# I can't get the intrinsic PACK to work as I think it should

Tags: fortran, pack

I am trying to use pack to return the indices of a character array where a certain letter occurs. I am using:

```
   results = pack([(az,az=1,10)],[((text(i) == testarray(1)),i=1,10)])
```

where `results` is an integer array and `text` and `testarray` are arrays of chars.

The code compiles correctly and appears to run but results is always empty. Can anyone assist me? I am an experienced Fortran programmer but have no experience using the pack function.

I expected that `results = pack([(az,az=1,c3)],[((text(i) == testarray(1)),i=1,c3)])` would use the implied do loop against the equality test to create a temp logical mask which would then be used to select for the array created by the `az` loop and give me the indices where the logical mask was true.
I am using GNU Fortran 12.1.0

Comment: What are some example values of the `text` and `testarray` arrays?

Comment: Your fist example works for me as expected. You have to show a full [mcve] that includes the initialization of your arrays to some particular values. The error can easily be there. See also [ask].

Comment: @Pete, do you mean "character arrays" or just "character" (with a length greater than 1)? If you want to find the indices of "A" in the ```character(len=...) word``` then just do ```results = pack( [ (i,i=1,len(word)) ], [ (word(i:i) == "A", i=1,len(word) ) ] )```